# In Python, how can I store a DataStructure in another module (triggered via a function) so that this DataStructure is available to that module

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to call a function from another module to create a dict in the module where that function is sitting in. That dict should then be available for all other funtions in that module.

I know if i just create that dict e.g. at the beginning of that module it will be available to the other functions of that module. However, the calculation of that dict takes long and I sometimes only want to create a smaller dataset.

I guess I could solve the problems with passing the data around, but ideally I would like it to be just created in the module.

```
#### Module.py
def CreateDict():
    SomeDict = {'1' : 'A'}

def UseDict():
    for key in SomeDict:
        print key

#### MainProgram.py
import Module as mo
mo.CreateDict()
mo.UseDict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
 #### Module.py
 def CreateDict():
     SomeDict = {'1' : 'A'}
     return SomeDict

 def UseDict(dict):
     for key in dict: #for key, value in dict.iteritems(): - is also useful
         print key

 #### MainProgram.py
 import Module as mo
 mydict = mo.CreateDict()
 mo.UseDict(mydict)
```

I suggest reading the [documentation for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) before posting on S/O

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was refering to with passing the dict around. I should have probably clarified what I meant with code. I waslooking for another possibility as I want to reduce the object to pass around.

Comment: unless you're working with performance-critical systems of some sort, the above example should work just fine for any application you look to build.